# Signal number to name?

Tags: c, unix

How can I quickly get signal name from its number?
There is `strsignal()`, but I just want the name, e.g. SIGUSR1

In other words, if we have macros like
`SIGUSR1 -> 12`
do we have anything like
`12 -> SIGUSR1` ?

Comment: In my `/usr/include/sys/signal.h`, all of the signal names are just `#define`d constants.  That means the preprocessor has already replaced them with constant integers by the time the compiler runs - the symbolic name *doesn't exist* as far as the program is concerned.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @CarlNorum, nothing special, just fancy output. I thought the actual names could be stored somewhere else so I could get them.

Comment: If you want "fancy output", isn't that exactly what `strsignal` is for?

Comment: Yeah it's fancy but not the way I want it :) Just curious, not an issue at all.

Comment: My `strsignal` man page says you can get the names directly from `sys_signame`.

Comment: @CarlNorum That one exactly. Thanks a lot! Didn't find this in my man page though.

Comment: OK, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

My [`strsignal(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsignal.3.html) man page says you can get the names directly from the `sys_signame` array.  Here's a simple example program I wrote to test it:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void upcase(char *s)
{
    while (*s)
    {
        *s = toupper(*s);
        s++;        
    }
}

int main(void)
{    
    for (int sig = 1; sig < NSIG; sig++)
    {
        char *str = strdup(sys_signame[sig]);
        if (!str)
            return -1;

        upcase(str);
        printf("%2d -> SIG%s\n", sig, str);

        free(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think this program produces the output you're looking for:

```
$ ./example 
 1 -> SIGHUP
 2 -> SIGINT
 3 -> SIGQUIT
 4 -> SIGILL
 5 -> SIGTRAP
 6 -> SIGABRT
 7 -> SIGEMT
 8 -> SIGFPE
 9 -> SIGKILL
10 -> SIGBUS
11 -> SIGSEGV
12 -> SIGSYS
13 -> SIGPIPE
14 -> SIGALRM
15 -> SIGTERM
16 -> SIGURG
17 -> SIGSTOP
18 -> SIGTSTP
19 -> SIGCONT
20 -> SIGCHLD
21 -> SIGTTIN
22 -> SIGTTOU
23 -> SIGIO
24 -> SIGXCPU
25 -> SIGXFSZ
26 -> SIGVTALRM
27 -> SIGPROF
28 -> SIGWINCH
29 -> SIGINFO
30 -> SIGUSR1
31 -> SIGUSR2
```

Comment: Only `strsignal` seems to be defined by POSIX it seems, array declarations like `sys_signame` seem to be extension.

Comment: So this is perhaps an answer to the problem the OP has if he's on OS X, but not an answer to the question as it is formulated.

Comment: ⁺¹, but note that array name was probably changed — it's [sys_siglist](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsignal.3.html).

Answer (score 7):

glib 2.32 (released on 2020-08-05) introduced the function `sigabbrev_np(int)`. Since that version you cannot use `sys_siglist[]` anymore too.

From `man strsignal`:

> The `sigabbrev_np()` function returns the abbreviated name of the signal, sig.  For example, given the value `SIGINT`, it returns the string `"INT"`.
> [...]
> sigdescr_np() and sigdabbrev_np() first appeared in glibc 2.32.
> Starting with version 2.32, the sys_siglist symbol is no longer exported by glibc.

And from the [release notes](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-announce/2020/000029.html):

> The functions `sigabbrev_np` and `sigdescr_np` have been added. The `sigabbrev_np` returns the abbreviated signal name (e.g. `"HUP"` for `SIGHUP`) [...] both functions return NULL for an invalid signal number.
>
> They should be used instead of `sys_siglist` or `sys_sigabbrev` and they are both thread and async-signal safe. These functions are GNU extensions.

Answer (score 3):

As [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) pointed out in comments years ago, *sys_signame* and *sys_siglist* are not portable.

Since this question is tagged `[unix]`, you can most portably `#ifdef` your way to a mapping of names and numeric values specific to your environment.  Something like:

```
//
//  const char * signame(int s)
//
//    return the name of the given signal number as a string,
//    or NULL if the number is unrecognized.
//
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <signal.h>

#define SIGNAMEANDNUM(s)  { #s, s }

static struct {
  const char *name,
  int value,
} known_signals[] = {
  SIGNAMEANDNUM(SIGABRT),   // get the POSIX signals
  SIGNAMEANDNUM(SIGALRM),
  SIGNAMEANDNUM(SIGBUS),
  SIGNAMEANDNUM(SIGCHLD),
  /* ... */
  SIGNAMEANDNUM(SIGXFSZ),
#ifdef SIGUNUSUAL           // get nonstandard signals 
  SIGNAMEANDNUM(SIGUNUSUAL),
#endif
  /* ... */
};

const char *
signame(int s) {
  const char *name = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(known_signals)/sizeof(*known_signals); i++) {
    if (s == known_signals[i].value) {
      name = known_signals[i].name;
      break;
    }
  }

  return name;
}
```

This requires some *a priori* knowledge of you platform, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Tested the below code on Ubuntu 22.04 and it works fine.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

extern const char * const sys_siglist[];

void upcase(char *s)
{
    while (*s)
    {
        *s = toupper(*s);
        s++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int sig;
   /*
    * NSIG returns the number of signals available in a system and it 
    * may vary according to platform; Found on Ubuntu-22.04 it returns 
    * 65 whereas in MIPS it is 31; Found in both platforms it leads to 
    * a core dump after signal 31 so limiting scanning of signal till 
    * 31 instead of using NSIG.
    */
    for (sig = 1; sig < 32; sig++)
    {
        char *str = strdup(strsignal(sig));
        if (!str)
            return -1;

        upcase(str);
        printf("%2d -> %s\n", sig, str);

        free(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code on Ubuntu-22.04 (Intel x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
 1 -> HANGUP
 2 -> INTERRUPT
 3 -> QUIT
 4 -> ILLEGAL INSTRUCTION
 5 -> TRACE/BREAKPOINT TRAP
 6 -> ABORTED
 7 -> BUS ERROR
 8 -> FLOATING POINT EXCEPTION
 9 -> KILLED
10 -> USER DEFINED SIGNAL 1
11 -> SEGMENTATION FAULT
12 -> USER DEFINED SIGNAL 2
13 -> BROKEN PIPE
14 -> ALARM CLOCK
15 -> TERMINATED
16 -> STACK FAULT
17 -> CHILD EXITED
18 -> CONTINUED
19 -> STOPPED (SIGNAL)
20 -> STOPPED
21 -> STOPPED (TTY INPUT)
22 -> STOPPED (TTY OUTPUT)
23 -> URGENT I/O CONDITION
24 -> CPU TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED
25 -> FILE SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED
26 -> VIRTUAL TIMER EXPIRED
27 -> PROFILING TIMER EXPIRED
28 -> WINDOW CHANGED
29 -> I/O POSSIBLE
30 -> POWER FAILURE
31 -> BAD SYSTEM CALL
```

Comment: but there's no SIGHANGUP or SIGINTERRUPT, they're SIGHUP and SIGINT. The ones with spaces are even more obviously wrong. The only that's right here is SIGQUIT...

Answer (score -2):

May be, you can declare a global array, like this

```
char *signame[]={"INVALID", "SIGHUP", "SIGINT", "SIGQUIT", "SIGILL", "SIGTRAP", "SIGABRT", "SIGBUS", "SIGFPE", "SIGKILL", "SIGUSR1", "SIGSEGV", "SIGUSR2", "SIGPIPE", "SIGALRM", "SIGTERM", "SIGSTKFLT", "SIGCHLD", "SIGCONT", "SIGSTOP", "SIGTSTP", "SIGTTIN", "SIGTTOU", "SIGURG", "SIGXCPU", "SIGXFSZ", "SIGVTALRM", "SIGPROF", "SIGWINCH", "SIGPOLL", "SIGPWR", "SIGSYS", NULL};
```

and can use it to print signal name in signal handler, like

```
void sig_handler(int signum){
     printf("Received signal : %s\n", signame[signum]);
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea because most signal numbers are implementation-dependent.  SIGKILL is always 9 but not all signals have fixed numbers like that.

Comment: but it is nice to have to use in a signal handler since strsignal is not signal-safe