# Platform agnostic way to convert signal numbers to strings

Tags: c++, boost

I have a signal handler in my program that looks like this:

```
void signalHandler(int sig)
{
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, fatal) << "Received signal " << sig;
    gQuit = true;
}
```

Currently this produces output like this:

> Received signal 2

But what I would like to see is something like

> Received signal SIGINT

I could probably replace the output of `sig` with `strsignal(sig)`, which [should work on POSIX.1-2008 systems](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsignal). This solution was discussed in this SO question:

[Signal number to name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509614/signal-number-to-name)

However, in my case I'd like to avoid the introduction of platform-specific code.

Do `boost` or the Standard Library provide a solution to this problem?

Comment: There are severe restrictions on what you can do in a signal handler and I'm not sure logging to a file is one of them. If that's what that code does. Anyway, you can simply look up the signal id in a table.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks, I wasn't aware there were restrictions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3787.html

Answer (score 0):

Well it's hard to prove a negative but I didn't find anything online and haven't got an answer, so I think it's;

No